# Continue Reading Link in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one field like Biography which is having a text, and I need to show half (some) of the text of that field on first page and then continue reading link appears, after clicking that link remaining text will be displayed on the same page

I need to achieve that in HTML.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: the splitting is better done on the server side. What language you use? PHP/ASP/ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is rapid prototyping. You can get better mileage if you are using jquery.

```
<div>

<span> Biography, first half ...</span>
<a href="javascript:showAll('bioSecondHalf')">Continue reading</a>

<span id="bioSecondHalf" style="display:none"> Biography, second half</span>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function showAll(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
   }
</script>
```

If you are starting with the full block of text and need to do everything client side:

```
<div id="biography" style="display:none">

Biography first half
Biography second half

</div>
```

If the block of text contains no markup html, then, you can grab the contents of the biography div and manipulate it on page load

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
   var bioText = document.getElementById("biography").innerHTML;
   var bioFirstHalf = bioText.substring(0,bioText.length/2);
   var bioSecondHalf = bioText.substring(bioText.length/2);
   document.getElementById("biography").innerHTML = bioFirstHalf + " <a href='javascript:showAll(\"bioSecondHalf\")'>Continue reading</a>" + " <span id='bioSecondHalf' style='display:none'>" + bioSecondHalf + "</span>"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me such a nice example, <span> Biography, first half ...</span>...Here I'm getting value from database like big text...so How can i cut half in javascript???..and how can i get remaining text??...please help me

Comment: how are you retrieving it from the database? if you are using some serverside code, such as php or jsp, you should use their string utilities. if you don't control the server side, how are you putting the code in the page? is it an ajax dump? I'll edit the post a bit...

Comment: <p>${BIOGRAPHY.getData()}</p>....dont focus on how it is coming from DB...from this ${BIOGRAPHY.getData()} i can get value of biography from the DB as a big text ...and that big text we have to cut it out and we have to show some of the its content on the first page itself...and after clicking that continue reading link..as u did it will show the remaining text..I'm using it is a VM template so this how value is coming..so through simple javascript i think we can achieve this..

Comment: the right way to do this is to cut it when dumping it to the page. you should find out what the string functions are to get string length and substring. then you can compose the <span> sections according to the template above and place the first and second portions in the right spots, so that all you do on the client side is to make the continue reading link display.  the method I described where you break the long string on the client side is a hack one would do only if you absolutely had no way to break the string on the server, but I suspect you can since you are building the page :)

Comment: Joe hv u checked that out???...because in that last stmt in javascript ...showing like..syntax error
[Break On This Error] }

Comment: yeah..its done..Thanks for ur help...but sample link which u sent in that after clicking that continue reading link ...something appears at the first line....Biography first half ..here after 'half' some characters are appearing what is that can u see it???

Answer (score 1):

### [Check out the demo](http://jsbin.com/uhigu3/2)

Code Used (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
  $('#readmore').click(function(){
    $('#hello').animate({height:'100%'});
    $(this).hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: if you're using jquery... which you should :), you may want to visually animate: $('#hello').show(1000); which will visually expand the area with a 1 second duration.

Answer (score 1):

see [this jquery plugin](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/playground/jquery-more-less-text/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You would wrap the text in a div and hide that div as soon as the DOM is ready. You would show the div when anyone clicks on the Continue Reading link. Additionally, you can achieve the show/hide effect by following following code:

```
    function toggle(element) {
document.getElementById(element).style.display = (document.getElementById(element).style.display == "none") ? "" : "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways to bind and do this... but the quick and dirty method...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="
    document.getElementById('more').style.display='block';
    this.style.display='none';
">show more</a>
<div id="more" style="display:none;">... more here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the data by using substring
assign `var x = ${BIOGRAPHY.getData()};`

then var y to show only the first 5 characters of var x which is your data.

```
var y = x.substring(0,5);
```

so if x = 123456789
then y will only show 12345

Then using jquery we can do

```
<div id="result">12345</div>
<a id="more" href="#">read more</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = '123456789';

    $('#more').click(function(){
        $('#result').text(x);
    });    

    </script>
```

Check working example here at
http://jsfiddle.net/alex00/7rn7Z/