# Show or hide text depending on length jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code that's working but there is some logical error.

Currently if the text is more than 200 characters, I want a button that says "continue reading." Right now the reverse is happening and I can't figure out why. When you click continue reading, it should show the rest of the text. Instead it hides the text. How can I fix this?

```js
 var showChar = 200;
 var ellipsestext = "...";
 var moretext = '<br><button class="continue-btn btn btn-success">Continue Reading</button>';
 var lesstext = '<br><button class="continue-btn btn btn-success">Show less</button>';
 jQuery('.featured-body').each(function() {
  var content = jQuery(this).html();

  if(content.length > showChar) {

   var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
   var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

   var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

   jQuery(this).html(html);
  }

 });

 jQuery(".morelink").click(function(){
  if(jQuery(this).hasClass("less")) {
   jQuery(this).removeClass("less");
   jQuery(this).html(moretext);
  } else {
   jQuery(this).addClass("less");
   jQuery(this).html(lesstext);
  }
  jQuery(this).parent().prev().toggle();
  jQuery(this).prev().toggle();
  return false;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="featured-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841875/continue-reading-link-in-javascript

Comment: This is going into Drupal and the view is building the content on the page. I've got to append the button to the text and this is the cleanest way I can think of. I also want to understand what is going on and why the logic is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. I think it'll work a bit better for you

HTML:

```
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="featured-body">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

var button = "<p><button class='continue-btn btn btn-success' id='act'>Continue Reading</button></p>";
var showChar = 200;   // Set a char limit
var ellipses = "<span id='ellip'>...</span>";

var pcount = $('.featured-body p:first').text().length;  // get paragraph char count

if(pcount > showChar){
   // split the paragraph in two
   var first_half  = $('.featured-body p').text().slice(0,200);
   var second_half = $('.featured-body p').text().slice(200,pcount);
  // erase the current paragraph text
  $('.featured-body p:first').text("");
 // Append the first and second halves, with new <div> classes, using :first because the button tag is wrapped in p, as it should be with HTML5
  $('.featured-body p:first').append("<div class='first'>"+first_half+ellipses+</div>");
  $('.featured-body p:first').append("<div class='second'>"+second_half+"</div>");
  $('.featured-body p:first').append(button);
 // Hide second half
 $('.second').hide();

}

$('#act').on('click',function(){ 
   // Toggle the second half on or off
   $('.second').toggle();
   $('#ellip').toggle();
  // Change the button text
  if($(this).text() == "Continue Reading"){
     $(this).text("Show Less")
  }else{
    $(this).text("Continue Reading");
  }
}); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments on this. I checked it in jsfiddle with no errors. hopefully not errors within Drupal. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can also cut it down by chaining stuff but for readability I left it

Comment: This works, I just can't get it to work in Drupal because I have to append the id=act button to the page otherwise Drupal gets the nodes confused and breaks. I also need the ellipses which I tried adding back, but couldn't remove on click again. :( Very frustrating that drupals own trim feature doesn't come with a show all button.

Comment: I'll change it so you don't have to modify any HTML, gimme a minute

Comment: You don't have to if you don't have time. I could go talk to my lead IT guy I just don't want to. lol. I'm trying to figure it out. Wish I wasn't such a scrub!

Comment: What are the ellipses for

Comment: Is that any better?

Comment: to append to the end of the word that is trimmed. Just to say basically "hey there's more to read after this word" The ellipsis should disappear once all the content is shown. I appended it to +first_half+elips+ earlier,

Comment: I'll try it out. I have a meeting to get to now. appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Nick0989 I added a var called ellipses that is appended with the first half when longer than chars, then down where you toggle .second, it also toggles that. Try that out. Should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code with a little tweaking from @clearshot68

Using a span tag instead of a div on the first_half, second_half variables puts the text inline.

```js
 var showChar = 1200;   // Set a char limit
 var ellipses = "<span id='ellip'>...</span>";
 var button = "<p><button class='continue-btn btn btn-success' id='act'>Continue Reading</button></p>";
 var pcount = $('.featured-body p:first').text().length;  // get paragraph char count

 if(pcount > showChar){
    // split the paragraph in two
    var first_half  = $('.featured-body p').text().slice(0,200);
    var second_half = $('.featured-body p').text().slice(200,pcount);
   // erase the current paragraph text
   $('.featured-body p:first').text("");
  // Append the first and second halves, with new <div> classes, using :first because the button tag is wrapped in p, as it should be with HTML5
   $('.featured-body p:first').append("<span class='first'>"+first_half+ellipses+"</span>");
   $('.featured-body p:first').append("<span class='second'>"+second_half+"</span>");
   $('.featured-body p:first').append(button);
  // Hide second half
  $('.second').hide();

 }

 $('#act').on('click',function(){ 
    // Toggle the second half on or off
    $('.second').toggle();
    $('#ellip').toggle();
   // Change the button text
   if($(this).text() == "Continue Reading"){
      $(this).text("Show Less")
   }else{
     $(this).text("Continue Reading");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

<body>
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="featured-body">
    <p>Before the floodplain restoration at Landis Homes was underway, residents were concerned about the view and asked for a planted screen to hide the wetland that was under construction.  Now, they wouldn’t dream of hiding the wetland, now flourishing with new flora and fauna. Home to more than 700 residents, the Landis Homes retirement community in Lititz, Pennsylvania, needed additional living space to meet demand for an increasing number of retirees. Landis Homes and their land development consultant RGS Associates contacted LandStudies, Inc., a local landscape architect firm specializing in floodplain restoration and regional stormwater solutions, for help. The team felt that restoring the floodplain would not only provide an amenity for the community, but also improve water quality and provide a unique stormwater management solution for the development. Over the course of three months, the team designed a stream and floodplain restoration project that improved stream function, increased floodwater storage potential, and actively engaged residents to improve social interactions and overall community health. By utilizing the floodplain for stormwater management, land that would be typically set aside for conventional stormwater management basins was used to construct additional housing units, increasing the efficiency of the overall development. 
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gah, only problem now is that you can't have multiple featured-body classes in separate divs that each button interacts with the closest feature-body.